# Laravel no reconoce ruta

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

estoy tratando de enviar un formulario via `POST` en `Laravel`, pro no encuentra, sale `error 404` y no tengo idea de porqué.

Ya he borrado caché reiniciado todo, pero no coje la ruta ni con `GET` ni `POST` ni nada, simplemente es como si no existiera

```
<form action="{{route('orderPay')}}" method="post" id="checkout" novalidate class="needs-validation">
                        @csrf
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="recibo" value="1" name="recibo" onclick="$('#book' ).toggle('fast')" checked>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="recibo">Datos Fiscales</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Se supone quieres usar esa ruta para hacer llegar el `$request` y procesarlo no?, o ¿quieres mostrar el formulario?

Comment: procesarlo, el formulario se muestra, pero este al enviar, no encuentra la ruta

Comment: Que tienes en `OrderController@pay`? Porque tal vez estes haciendo un redirect

Comment: no hay ningun redirect, `return $request->all()` es todo lo que hay en `OrderController@pay`

Comment: @user75463 donde esta tu `button` submit? O lo haces con AJAX?

Comment: Hay una ruta con parámetro que puede estar interfiriendo. Pon el código como texto, así se copiar y pegar